# Query binding adding slashes.. prevents me from doing searches

Tags: mysql, binding

I am trying to search a store by its name, and when using mysql data binding, it adds a slash in between and prevents me from searching for the store name

The store name is Jimmy's Pita

When I run the query it looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE store_name = 'Jimmy\'s Pita'
```

But the store name in the database looks like this ...  'Jimmy's Pita & Poke'

What can I do to fix this issue?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with escaping. When you specify using single quotes you must escape other single quotes, as in:

```
'Jimmy\'s Pita'
```

If you use different quotes, which MySQL allows by default, then you can do this instead:

```
"Jimmy's Pita"
```

Both of these are equivalent and in both cases the data saved is:

```
Jimmy's Pita
```

The backslash is *only* there to deal with escaping issues. It is not literally part of the data.

When it comes to searching you may want to use the MySQL full-text index so you can get "close enough" matches, like searching for "jimmys pita" and so on.